# PHP - How to sort and array acording posion in 'helper array' when numeric 'foreach keys' are missing

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have `array1` like this:

```
[user2] => 27
[user3] => 30
[user4] => 33
[user5] => 36
[user6] => 39
[user10] => 39
[user12] => 42
```

Using second (helper, `authority`) array:

```
[user2] => 6
[user3] => 7
[user4] => 1
[user5] => 4
[user6] => 3
[user10] => 2
[user12] => 5
```

And I want to sort `array1` like this

```
[user2] => 27
[user3] => 30
[user4] => 33
[user5] => 36
[user10] => 39 // user10 goes before user6
[user6] => 39
[user12] => 42
```

Algorithms is: When rows in `array1` has same value, check `authority array` and reorder same value rows according it. The lower value, the higher (earlier) it goes in sorted `array1` (`user10` has value `2` in `authority array` and therefore it goes before `user6` which has value `3` in `authority array`).

`array1` is order of users based on vote of various senators. There is also "president of senate". When you have users with same results (`user6` and `user10`) reorder them according the preference of "president".

Another possible input is:

```
$arr = [
    "user7" => 15,
    "user11" => 15,
    "user4" => 30,
    "user19" => 36,
    "user10" => 39,
];

$helper = [
    "user4" => 3,
    "user7" => 2,
    "user10" => 4,
    "user11" => 1,
    "user19" => 5,
];
```

while this is desired output

```
Array
(
    [user11] => 15
    [user7] => 15
    [user4] => 30
    [user19] => 36
    [user10] => 39
)
```

Comment: Just use array_multisort

Comment: So, `user2` has value `6` and user4 has value `1`, so can you tell us how `user2` came before `user4` after sorting?

Comment: I believe he meant primary order by the first array and when encounter equality decide according the second array (that why the use of `array_multisort`

Comment: @dWinder Ok, it makes sense now but OP's definition needs to be revamped if this is the case. Also, it can be done without array_multisort too as the another answer states.

Comment: @vivek_23 `array1` is order of users based on vote of various senators. There is also "president of senate". When you have users with same results (`user6` and `user10`) reorder them according the preference of "president".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `array_keys` and `array_flip` to get order array. Use `uksort` to sort the array based on `order`

```
$arr = ....
$helper = ...
$order = array_flip(array_keys( $helper ));
uksort ( $arr , function( $a , $b ) use ( $order, $arr, $helper ) {
    if ( $arr[$a] != $arr[$b] ) return $order[$a] - $order[$b];
    return $helper[$a] - $helper[$b];
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$arr = [
    "user7" => 15,
    "user11" => 15,
    "user4" => 30,
    "user19" => 36,
    "user10" => 39,
];

$helper = [
    "user4" => 3,
    "user7" => 2,
    "user10" => 4,
    "user11" => 1,
    "user19" => 5,
];

uksort ( $arr , function( $a , $b ) use ( $arr, $helper ) {
    if ( $arr[$a] != $arr[$b] ) return $arr[$a] - $arr[$b];
    return $helper[$a] - $helper[$b];
});
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [user11] => 15
    [user7] => 15
    [user4] => 30
    [user19] => 36
    [user10] => 39
)
```

Comment: Yes @Eddie , you are right with the resulting array. But I need `user10` before `user6` because in authority array `user10` has lower value (2) then `user6` (3).

Comment: it seems you have solved it. I will test it later this day but for now it does exactly what I need. Good bless you :)

Comment: I have found an undesired behavior in edited function code (I have edited your answer). What do you thing, may you fix it?

Comment: Edit your post. Not the answer. You have to specify what behavior or rules you want to implement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193536/discussion-between-jasom-dotnet-and-eddie).

Comment: Ok, this new version is better since original input works too. Thank you 2.0 :-D

Comment: Glad to hear :)